# What is single word for "behind the bars"?

Tags: single-word-requests

I have heard of the term 'behind the bars'. Is there any single worded-term for this?

Comment: **Bartender** (in multiple locations). If you meant ***behind bars***, it is "jailed"

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because OP is asking about a phrase in a specific context, but cannot remember the context. (see comments).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jailed? Incarcerated? If not those, they're a place to start a thesaurus search.

And I would bet the term you heard is "behind bars" not "behind the bars".

Comment: Unless talking about barmaids (as you do).

Comment: @TimLymington: As we do indeed. But all the barmaids I've talked about (or ***to***) work *behind the **bar***. I never heard of anyone working behind multiple bars.

Comment: _All the girls working behind the bars at Hooters are supposed to be attractive_

Comment: Although this might be apprpriate for a bar with a prison theme.

Comment: Well, all of you might be perfectly right. But I just read the term **behind the bars**.

Comment: @AfzaalAhmadZeeshan: Where? 'Behind the bars' does not have a meaning in general: it may have one in a specific context, in which case we may be able to help.

Comment: @TimLymington, yes, that is why I was not able to find anything related to it. I heard my friend read it in a magazine of his university..

Answer (score 0):

"**Apprehend**" might be the word you looking for.